# DataGridCheckBoxColumn checkboxes showing two lists intersections

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have two `ObservableCollection<T>` let's call them List1 and List2. List1 contains some items from List2.
What I would like to do is to have `DataGrid` CheckBoxColumn to tick items that are in List1 and List2. Other columns show info of the viewVodel of the item.

What would be the best way of achieving this?
By the way `DataGrid` is defined in template and I'm doing it the MVVM way.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a converter like

```
public class ItemToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // Here value is the item from List 1
            List<T> list2 = (List<T>)parameter;
            return list2.Contains(value as T);

        }

    }
```

and then declare a CheckBoxColumn

```
<DataGrid ...>    
 <DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding myItemfromList1, Converter={StaticResource ItemToBooleanConverter1}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource List2}}" />
 </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

You cannot directly bind your List2 to converter parameter, but you can declare a StaticResource  or programmatically create the converter passing the List2 as parameter.